# How to get a daily report of the exit codes of cron jobs

Tags: debian, cron, email, devuan

I have a few dozen cron jobs, which run every day, for backups.

- I don't want to receive an email for only failed jobs, as I won't know when the email fails.
- I don't want to receive an email for every job, as that would be too many to check.

I would like a single daily email report of the exit codes of those jobs.  Ideally the subject line will change if any of the exit codes are non-zero.

My current thought is that I will turn these jobs into a single shell script which can collect the return codes and then send the email.

Getting a single daily report from cron seems like a common requirement.  Are there already tools or settings which will do this for me?

Comment: I do not think there is such tool. You should create own, just collect in file the exit codes and once per day get recapitulation.

Comment: To echo Romeo's comment: You will need to: 1) use a redirect to collect feedback (in log files) from your individual `cron` jobs, 2) write a script that reviews these log files.